# How do I parse string FQL to a query using faunadb-js?

Tags: faunadb

Let's say I have a string like `const fql = "CreateCollection({ name: "users" })"`. How do I turn it into a faunadb `Expr` in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You landed on the correct answer yourself. FQL is not a string-based language. This approach avoids problems like SQL injection, but it does mean you need to compose queries *somewhere* using a driver, the console, or a tool like [Fauna Schema Migrate](https://github.com/fauna-labs/fauna-schema-migrate) (FSM).

```
const fql = "CreateCollection({ name: "users" })"
```

The example you give leans toward schema/resource management. If that's your actual need here, consider FSM or the [Fauna Serverless Framework plugin](https://github.com/fauna-labs/serverless-fauna).

If you're building a front-end app using JavaScript, FSM is probably the right approach as it drops right into your app. **It might also give you some more hints at how to transform strings into FQL.** You would do the above in a single FQL file, e.g., `fauna/resources/collections/users.fql` as:

```
CreateCollection({ name: "users" })
```

If you're doing infrastructure as code in a separate pipeline or are already building with the [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com), the plugin might be a better fit.

If you want to see something else like a Pulumi or [Terraform provider plugins](https://forums.fauna.com/t/terraform-provider/850/8), please submit a [feature request](https://forums.fauna.com/c/feature-requests/2) in the forums!

Comment: Thanks! My use case is programmatically instantiating a local test database, yep. I think FSM does not support this yet (it's one of the things listed under "potential extensions"). I have a working solution for now just defining my schema in a .ts file.

Comment: "programmatically instantiating a local test database" --> 

Check out the tests in Fwitter, e.g. the [fweet spec](https://github.com/fauna-labs/fwitter/blob/main/src/fauna/queries/fweets.spec.js) 

They're written in JavaScript, but do create child databases from the given key.

For the "local" part - see [Fauna Dev](https://hub.docker.com/r/fauna/faunadb)

You'll need to point the `domain` property to your local instance when creating your client. See [this example](https://github.com/fauna/faunadb-js#connecting-from-the-browser)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this at the moment seems to be evaluating the FQL as JavaScript.

The fauna-shell [eval command](https://github.com/fauna/fauna-shell/blob/main/src/commands/eval.js#L51) is implemented using esprima to parse the FQL as ECMAScript, then running it through node's `vm` api with escodegen.

It's likely easier to just rewrite FQL files as JS files if you have the option!